# Is the "Clean Up" phase of TimeMachine necessary?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, backup, time-machine, monterey

I am using a fresh drive via USB A to SATA 3 to use as a TimeMachine backup. The back up didn't take very long however the the "Clean Up" phase is taking just as long if not longer than the backup.

Is this "Clean Up" stage of TimeMachine backups necessary, especially for fresh drives, or can it be skipped?

Comment: I don't recommend skipping it, no - it'll likely start over the cleanup phase when you reconnect if you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the "Clean Up" stage of Time Machine is necessary for its function and cannot be skipped while keeping the whole functionality of Time Machine backups.