# Time machine backup is "cleaning up" even there is widely enough storage space (Ventura)?

Tags: backup, time-machine, ventura

Since i upgraded to Ventura on my Mac, Time Machine Backups is cleaning up even there is widely enough storage space onthe backup disk.
Can somebody help here?

Comment: Have you seen [this Q&A](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/438341/is-the-clean-up-phase-of-timemachine-necessary)? What exactly do you need help with? Pls be more specific.